# clustering 3D array in R

Tags: arrays, r, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to cluster 3D data that I have in an array. It's actually information from a 3D image so this array represents a single image with x,y,z values. I would like to know what voxel tends to cluster with what. The array looks like this.

```
 dim(x)
[1] 34 34 34  1
```

How can I go about this? I tried just plotting with scatterplot3d but it did not work.

Comment: What did you try? Show us your code.

Comment: this didn't work (not that this clusters): scatterplot3d(x[,,,1]) and dist(x[,,,1]) just doesn't finish.

Comment: Your matrix seems to have 4 dimensions (34,34,34,1). What is the meaning of the last dimension?

Comment: Do you want clustering or [segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation)?

Comment: the last dimension of the array signifies I have 1 three-dimensional matrix of dimensions 34X34X34. If inside array x I had 2 3D matrices, they would be represented as (34,34,34,2). @VincentZoonekynd what I want is segmentation I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is an attempt at clustering. You really should provide data if you want a better answer.

```
library(reshape2)   # for melt(...)
library(rgl)        # for plot3d(...)

set.seed(1)         # to create reproducible sample

# 3D matrix, values clustered around -2 and +2
m      <- c(rnorm(500,-2),rnorm(500,+2))
dim(m) <- c(10,10,10) 
v      <- melt(m, varnames=c("x","y","z"))  # 4 columns: x, y, z, value
# interactive 3D plot, coloring based on value
plot3d(v$x,v$y,v$z, col=1+round(v$value-min(v$value)),size=5)
# identify clusters
v      <- scale(v)                          # need to scale or clustering will fail
v      <- data.frame(v)                     # need data frame for later
d  <- dist(v)                               # distance matrix
km <- kmeans(d,centers=2)                   # kmeans clustering, 2 clusters
v$clust <- km$cluster                       # identify clusters
# plot the clusters
plot(z[1:4],col=v$clust)                    # scatterplot matrix
plot3d(v$x,v$y,v$z, col=v$clust,size=5)     # 3D plot, colors based in cluster
```

The main idea is to reshape your 3D matrix into "long" format with columns for x, y, z, and the actual matrix values. So now x, y, and z contain the positional information (here, the index values 1:10). You need to scale this so the `value` column and the index columns are on the same scale, otherwise clustering will give you misleading results.

[image]

[image]