# spatial clustering 3d array with neighbourhood strategy in r

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, cluster-analysis, spatial

I need to perform spatial clustering within a 3d array using a neighbourhood strategy. To be more clear: I have a 3d image that is represented as a sparse 3d array. Some of the instances are 1 while most of them are 0. I would like to cluster together instances equal to 1 that are neighbour to each other (i.e. if we imagine each instance as a cube, I would like to group together instances that share a face, an edge or a corner and are equal to 1).

I need to do this in R since this step is part of a longer pipeline for machine learning, and I am trying to implement the whole pipeline within a single environment to minimize headache.
I have found an answered questions slightly related to the present one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343834/clustering-3d-array-in-r). However, in that case, the number of clusters was known beforehand, while in my case the number of clusters could be anything from 1 to the number of instances equal to 1 (provided that no instance is neighbour with another one).

I could write a function to this aim, but it would be time consuming and probably not very efficient, as I cannot think to any other strategy than looking for non-zero instances, check every neighbour instances, if any of these is non-zero, than check its neighbours and so on.

Since the clustering step is included in a nested-cross validation loop you can see for yourself that I would need something more efficient (or maybe just the same thing written in C, in order to be faster).

Is any of you aware of any function or package that could help me ?

**Update**

To answer to a comment, my "sparse" array is sparse in the sense that most of the elements are zero, not in the sense that it is saved in a sparse format.
Here a toy example (that is indeed a crop around the non-zero elements of my original array, that have dim (91,109,91)).

```
sparse_array = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(13L, 3L, 6L))
```

**Update 2**

I am working on a Windows x64 machine, with RStudio 1.0.153 and R version 3.4.2 (Short Summer)

**Update 3**

I have tried the answer given by @gdkrmr, and while it works fine for the example given, it fails to generalize to bigger and more complex images. Specifically, it over-segregates the clusters in my image, meaning that voxels that do indeed touch each other are sometimes split in different clusters.
You can visualize it yourself downloading this [image](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AinpKVLkRgtceME3klypNyjfpWs) and running the following code

read 3d images

```
library(oro.nifti)
roi <- readNIfTI("image_to_cluster.nii")
roi_img <- cal_img(roi)
```

read data as array

```
array_img <- roi@.Data
```

transform in sparse format

```
sparse_format <- (array_img > 0) %>%
  which(., arr.ind = TRUE)
```

find neighbouring voxels

```
neighborhoods <- sparse_format %>%
  dist %>%
  as.matrix %>%
  {. < 2}
```

assign clusters labels

```
cluster <- 1:nrow(sparse_format)
for (i in 1:nrow(sparse_format)) {
  cl_idx <- cluster[i]
  cluster[neighborhoods[, i]] <- cl_idx
}
sparse_format <- sparse_format %>%
  as_data_frame(.) %>%
  mutate(cluster_id = cluster)
```

write the clusters to a new 3d image

```
new_img <- roi
new_img@.Data <- array(0,c(74,92,78))

for (cl in cluster) {
  new_img@.Data[sparse_format %>% filter(., cluster_id == cl) %>% select(dim1,dim2,dim3) %>% as.matrix] <- cl
}
writeNIfTI(new_img, "test", verbose=TRUE)
```

Now if you open the file `test.nii.gz` (you can do it with e.g. [mricron](http://people.cas.sc.edu/rorden/mricron/index.html)) you will see that there is one big cluster at roughly coordinates `37 23 15`which has been splitted in 3 different clusters, even if all voxels are connected.

Comment: 1) You could use the the `Rcpp` package if performance is important to you. 2) Using the `dist` function on the indices should work in a 3d array, every two points with a distance `< 2` should be neighbors, but this stops working for `d > 3`. 3) I also guess that your algorithm can be orders of magnitude faster, if the indices of your 3d array are sorted.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You go a little bit too fast for me:
1 - I looked at the Rcpp package, and I am not sure how I can use it for my aim.
2 - Thanks for the tip
3 - What do you mean with point 3 ?

Comment: 1) you would use Rcpp to implement your own algorithm in C/C++ Rcpp simply makes interfacing C++ and R easier. 3) If you implement your own algorithm and know, that the indices are sorted, you do not need to compare all points vs. all points, i.e. in the 1D case: if the indices or your ones are: `c(1, 3, 4, 5)` you know, that the first two are no neighbors after checking only the first two elements.

Comment: One question: Is your array saved in a sparse format or is it a dense array that is sparse in the sense that it consists mostly of zeros? That is why you should always provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I have updated the question to answer @gdkrmr question and added a reproducible exampkle

Comment: I can't run the code in update 3:  `could not find function "readNIfTI"`. Should some package be loaded?

Comment: So sorry, I miss a line in my copy paste of the code. I have edited the question including `library(oro.nifti)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `spatstat` package to do this. You need the newly
created branch `connected.pp3` from github which can be installed if you
have either `devtools` or `remotes` package loaded (here I use
`remotes`):

```r
library(remotes)
install_github("spatstat/spatstat")

library(spatstat)
```

Grid and bounding box

```r
grid <- expand.grid(0:4,0:4,0:4)
bb <- box3(range(grid[,1]), range(grid[,2]), range(grid[,3]))
```

Sparse array of data (and the id of the sparse rows)

```r
grid$id <- 1:nrow(grid)
set.seed(42)
a <- grid[sample(nrow(grid), 20),]
a
#>     Var1 Var2 Var3  id
#> 115    4    2    4 115
#> 117    1    3    4 117
#> 36     0    2    1  36
#> 102    1    0    4 102
#> 78     2    0    3  78
#> 63     2    2    2  63
#> 88     2    2    3  88
#> 16     0    3    0  16
#> 77     1    0    3  77
#> 82     1    1    3  82
#> 53     2    0    2  53
#> 116    0    3    4 116
#> 106    0    1    4 106
#> 29     3    0    1  29
#> 52     1    0    2  52
#> 104    3    0    4 104
#> 107    1    1    4 107
#> 13     2    2    0  13
#> 51     0    0    2  51
#> 60     4    1    2  60
```

Convert to 3D point pattern and find connected components (returned as
so-called marks to the points). As pointed out by @gdkrmr any point with
distance less than 2 is a neighbour (here we use 1.8, but anything
between sqrt(3) and 2 should work).

```r
x <- pp3(a[,1], a[,2], a[,3], bb)
x_labelled <- connected.pp3(x, R = 1.8)
df <- data.frame(cluster_id = marks(x_labelled), point_id = a$id)
```

For nicer printing we sort according to cluster id

```r
df[order(df$cluster_id, df$point_id),]
#>    cluster_id point_id
#> 1           1      115
#> 14          2       29
#> 19          2       51
#> 15          2       52
#> 11          2       53
#> 20          2       60
#> 6           2       63
#> 9           2       77
#> 5           2       78
#> 10          2       82
#> 7           2       88
#> 4           2      102
#> 16          2      104
#> 13          2      106
#> 17          2      107
#> 12          2      116
#> 2           2      117
#> 8           3       16
#> 3           3       36
#> 18          4       13
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I am having some problem installing the developer version of `spatstat`. I have installed the `remotes` package but when I run the comand `install_github("spatstat/spatstat", ref = "connected.pp3")` I got an error message stating that R cannot find the url `'https://api.github.com/repos/spatstat/spatstat/zipball/connected.pp3'`. Any idea about what's happening ?

Comment: I'm sorry about this. The new function was merged into the master branch and the `connected.pp3` branch was deleted. I have now updated the answer to reflect this. Let me know whether it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarification. However, I have working on a Windows machine (sorry for not specifying it in the question, I have edited it now) and I think this create some problem. When I run the `install_github("spatstat/spatstat")`bit, R does download the package, but I guess cannot compile it, as I see a message stating that `the execution of the command "make -c [...]" had non-zero exit. ERROR compilation failed`. Is there a workaround for Windows that you know ?

Comment: You can download the Windows binary here (zip file spatstat_xxx.zip at the bottom): https://ci.appveyor.com/project/baddstats/spatstat/build/artifacts

Comment: It seems that I will never be able to try out your answer: the binary has been compiled for 32-bit and not 64, so R will not load the library. Again, I could switch to a 32-bit version of R, but I really want to keep all the steps of my pipe-line within one software and session.

Comment: I have now updated to 64 bit on Appveyor. Please try to download and install again.

Comment: That did the trick! Very short running time (0.03552389 secs) even with the bigger image. Right now the most time consuming step is go back to non sparse format and reassign the cluster index values to the appropriate voxel in the image. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure R solution, it takes advantage that the maximum distance of neighboring voxels is `sqrt(d) < 2` if `d <= 3`:

```
library(rgl)
library(magrittr)
sparse_format <- (sparse_array > 0) %>%
  which(., arr.ind = TRUE)
neighborhoods <- sparse_format %>%
  dist %>%
  as.matrix %>%
  {. < 2}
n <- nrow(sparse_format)

perm <- 1:n
for (i in 1:n) {
  perm[i:n] <- perm[i:n][
    order(neighborhoods[perm[i], perm][i:n], 
          decreasing = TRUE)
  ]
}
neighborhoods <- neighborhoods[perm, perm]
sparse_format <- sparse_format[perm, ]

cluster <- 1:n
for (i in 1:n) {
  cl_idx <- cluster[i]
  cluster[neighborhoods[, i]] <- cl_idx
}
plot3d(sparse_format, col = cluster)
```

UPDATE: Added sorting of the `neighborhoods` matrix to find the connected clusters. This has become very slow (~30s for your example image), but I think that there is still a lot of room for optimization. If you want a really fast solution look at the [Julia](http://julialang.org) language, especially at [Images.jl](https://github.com/JuliaImages/Images.jl/blob/master/src/connected.jl).

UPDATE: Made the first loop fast.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer works, but I am ashamed to say that I do not understand exactly how. I understand the overall logic: the core is in `cluster[neighborhoods[, i]] <- cl_idx`, where you assign the current (ith) cluster label to all indexes that are `TRUE` in the ith column of `neighborhoods`. However, in the end, in `cluster` I only find (correctly) cluster labels 1 and 2. How is this possible since the for command is looping from 1 to 20 ?

Comment: To a second check, your answer works suboptimal. While it works fine on the example provided, it partially fails to generalize. If I try it on a "more complex" image, it segregated the different clusters, but sometimes it "over-segregate", splitting voxels that are indeed neighbour. I have updated my questions with an example that show the failure.

Comment: You are right, there is somewhere a bug in my example, I can make it work on your example data with and additional backwards pass. This is not ideal, because I do not understand yet why it failed in the first place.

Comment: I think it finds still 10 instead of 9 clusters

Comment: I hope this works now, even though it has become terribly slow.

Comment: Indeed it works. Just for you to know, I am not accepting the answer because of speed consideration, that were mentioned in the question, but otherwise I acknowledge your help. I will use your answer as a starting point and see if I can make it faster. In that case I will accept the answer. Thanks for all the inputs.

Comment: I think it should be possible to only reorder a vector length `n` in the first loop and to do the permutation of `neighborhoods` and `sparse_format` after exiting the loop only once. The second loop can probably be simplified by looking only at the 1-off diagonal of `neighborhoods`

Comment: Made the first loop fast!